# XML Sorting with php without XSL

Tags: xml

How can we sort an xml file in php without using an xsl?Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize your XML document into objects, then sort them and serialize again. Here is the manual for serialization: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 0):

Read in and parse the file, convert it to an array, sort, generate XML, then output.

Or just use XSLT.